# Media only screen for Android devices

Tags: android, ios, html, css

I am using the below media screen queries to display images properly for iPhone/ipad works fine. However i am not sure what should i do for andriod phones ? It displays image in its original form ?

```
/* iphone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}

@media print {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/* iphone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 480px) and (max-device-width : 640px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 640px) and (max-device-width : 768px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}


@media print {
    img { max-width: 100%; }
}
```